# C++ Text Message Decoder script Compiler "expects unqualified id" before if and else statements

Tags: c++

Help! I'm new in C++.  I wrote this code for the purpose of decoding text abbreviations and my compiler keeps giving me Error: "expected unqualified id" before my if and else statements.  No matter what I'm trying I can't seem to fix this error.  Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> // Note: This library is needed to use the string type
using namespace std;

int main() {

string abbr;
cout << "Input the abbreviation: " ;
cin >> abbr;

string LOL = "laughing out loud";
string IDK = "I don't know";
string BFF = "best friends forever";
string IMHO = "in my humble opinion";
string TMI = "too much information";
}

if (abbr = "LOL") == 0) ||
  (abbr = "lol") == 0))
{
  cout << "Laughing out loud";
}

else if (abbr = "IDK") == 0) ||
      (abbr = "idk") == 0))
{
  cout << "I don't know";
}

else if (abbr = "BFF") == 0) ||
      (abbr = "bff") == 0))
{
  cout << "best friends forever";
}

else if (abbr = "IMHO") == 0) ||
      (abbr = "imho") == 0))
{
  cout << "in my humble opinion";
} 

else if (abbr = "TMI") == 0) ||
      (abbr = "tmi") == 0))
{
  cout << "too much information";
}

else
  cout << "Unknown";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you think you are programming in C and C++.  I suggest you remove the C tag and focus on C++.

Comment: Why are you using `strcmp` with `std::string`?  You could have something like: `if (abbr == "LOL")`.

Comment: See `std::transform` for converting a string to all lower or all upper case, so you only make ` comparison. Otherwise, 'lOl" will mess up your program as well as other letter/case combinations.

Comment: You have an open brace `{` after the `cout` in the last `else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

All you have wrong is your bracing. You close `main()` before you get to the if statements. All you need to do is get rid of the `}` after you declare your strings and fix the parentheses on the if statements. As you are writing your code, try to insert pairs of parentheses instead of just one, and you should have less issues. Here is the fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> // Note: This library is needed to use the string type
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string abbr;
    cout << "Input the abbreviation: ";
    cin >> abbr;

    string LOL = "laughing out loud";
    string IDK = "I don't know";
    string BFF = "best friends forever";
    string IMHO = "in my humble opinion";
    string TMI = "too much information";


if((strcmp(abbr.c_str(), "LOL") == 0) ||
(strcmp(abbr.c_str(), "lol") == 0))
{
    cout << "Laughing out loud";
}

else if((strcmp(abbr.c_str(), "IDK") == 0) ||
(strcmp(abbr.c_str(), "idk") == 0))
  {
  cout << "I don't know";
  }

else if((strcmp(abbr.c_str(), "BFF") == 0) ||
(strcmp(abbr.c_str(), "bff") == 0))
  {
  cout << "best friends forever";
  }

else if((strcmp(abbr.c_str(), "IMHO") == 0) ||
(strcmp(abbr.c_str(), "imho") == 0))
  {
  cout << "in my humble opinion";
  }

else if((strcmp(abbr.c_str(), "TMI") == 0) ||
(strcmp(abbr.c_str(), "tmi") == 0))
  {
  cout << "too much information";
  }

else
{
    cout << "Unknown";
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And you would also need to addd `#include <cstring>` for `strcmp`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix C and C++, that's a bad idea. If you want to use C function, then
stick to C, if you want to use C++, then use the function C++ provides.

If you would have proper indentation, you would have seen right away that you
curly braces are at the wrong places. After `string TMI = "too much information";`
you have a closing `}` which ends the `main` function. After that you are
calling `if` outside a function, the compiler complains about that.

Also your `if`s are missing the first `(`

```
  // misses (
  //   v
else if (strcmp(abbr.c_str(), "IDK") == 0) ||
          (strcmp(abbr.c_str(), "idk") == 0))
```

also `strcmp` is a C function defined in `string.h`. In order to use that in
C++, you need to add `#include<cstring>` to have access to `strcmp`.

But like I said, if you are using C++, then use the tools that C++ provide
instead of mixing them with C. You shouldn't think that C++ is a C extension.

Using C++ tools you can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

int main(void)
{
    std::string abbr;
    std::cout << "Input the abbreviation: " ;
    std::cin >> abbr;

    std::map<std::string, std::string> abbr_map = {
        {"lol",  "laughing out loud"},
        {"idk",  "I don't know"},
        {"bff",  "best friends forever"},
        {"imho", "in my humble opinion"},
        {"tmi",  "too much information"},
    };

    std::string orig = abbr;

    std::transform(abbr.begin(), abbr.end(), abbr.begin(), ::tolower);

    if(abbr_map.find(abbr) == abbr_map.end())
    {
        std::cerr << "Abbreviation '" << orig << "' not found" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << abbr_map[abbr] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```